# Yield from parent's section

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've got the section in my master template

```
@section('errors')
    // ...
@stop
```

I wanna yield it in some specific place of my other page, I extended that page from master template and yielding the section

```
@extends('template')

@yield('errors')
```

But nothing is yielded. I assume that I am just doing this wrong. Is there the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you put in master template:

```
@yield('errors')
```

and in child template you use:

```
@section('errors')
    // ...
@stop
```

to display something in place when in master template you used `@yield('errors')`

But in your case if this section appears on many pages you can use in parent template:

```
@yield('errors')
```

and in child template:

```
@section('errors')
    @include ('errors')
@stop
```

and create new `errors.blade.php` file that displays error.

Of course everything depends on your needs. You can of course also in parent template use:

```
@include ('errors')
```

instead of yielding.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I thought about include but wanted to avoid any extra includes, but seems there is no other way.